# How to avoid getting highlighted two cells in a tableview?

Tags: ios, uitableview, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

Hi in my application i am using one tableview and each cell contains one collection view. When i select one cell in tableview that cell should highlight in light gray and previous should change to black this i am doing as like below.

```
-(void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    collectionView.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];

    collectionViewTagValue=collectionView.tag;
    nextFocusedIndex=indexPath;


    selectedCollectionCellTag=collectionView.tag;


                // Get previously selected collectionview tag value(Because we have many collectionvies in table)

                NSIndexPath *previousPath=[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:self->appdelegateObject.guideSelectionTag inSection:0];

                // Get Tableview cell based on tag value - that tag value will be a tableview row number

                DetailTableViewCell *cell = (DetailTableViewCell*)[self->guideDetailsTable cellForRowAtIndexPath:previousPath];

                // Get indexpath of a selected cell in collection view

                NSIndexPath *previouslySelectedCell=[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:self->appdelegateObject.guideSelectionIndex inSection:0];

                // Get collectionview cell based on indexpath value

                MainCollectionViewCell *previousCell = (MainCollectionViewCell*)[cell.collection cellForItemAtIndexPath:previouslySelectedCell];

                // Change celllabel background color to normal not highlight

                previousCell.cellLable.backgroundColor=[UIColor colorWithRed:0.073 green:0.073 blue:0.073 alpha:1.0];

                MainCollectionViewCell *currentCell = (MainCollectionViewCell*)[collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];

                currentCell.cellLable.backgroundColor=[UIColor lightGrayColor];


}
```

using above code sometimes both previous and current cells are getting highlighted with light gray.Even if i did this change in dispatch_main_queue also same behaviour i observed. Can any one please suggest best approach for this feature.

Note : For first cell selection i am getting collectionview.tag as -1.

Comment: as you mention it happen some time, it could related to responded. i.e when you click on cell which delegate call table one or collection one ?

Answer (score 0):

Implemented following method to fix your issue:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    let yourCell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)

    yourCell?.backgroundColor = UIColor.black
}
```

This code in Swift, you need to convert it to Objective-C.

This method call for previous cell which you have selected, it being deselect.

Answer (score 0):

```
//add condition in tableView delegate in didselect or diddeSelect, check index.section..
    //for selected cell
    -(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

         UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *)[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
// check indexPath.Section here
if (!indexPath.section) == 0{ 
         cell.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor yellowColor];
}

    }

    //for other cells
    -(void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didDeselectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
// check indexPath.Section here
if (!indexPath.section) == 0{ 
       cell.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
      }
    }
// hope its works for you!
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)
        cell?.contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)
        cell?.contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGray
    }
```

[image: you need to set selection Default as well]